# Checking whether HTTPRequest is "real" or we are running headless (unit test) in Plone

Tags: plone

I discovered an issue with Plone's RegistrationTool and PasswordResetTool

- https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13173

Template mail_password_response.pt gets rendered even if no HTTPRequest has been made. This template is a full frame Plone page relying on a main_template. main_template has viewlets which rely the present of real HTTPRequest object, namely its ACTUAL_URL parameter.

How to fix the situation like this? Obviously mail_password_response.pt should not be rendered if there is not a browser to display the results. But how one checks in deep Plone code whether HTTPRequest is "real" which should yield to UI response á la awful ZMI manage_xxx hacks?

What would be the proper fix to the problem? Is it making RegistrationTool not to render the template or making viewlets safe against incomplete, test stub, HTTPRequest objects?

This the viewlets bit needing ACTUAL_URL in p.a.layout.viewlets.common

```
class ContentViewsViewlet(ViewletBase):


    @memoize
    def prepareObjectTabs(self, default_tab='view', sort_first=['folderContents']):
        """Prepare the object tabs by determining their order and working
        out which tab is selected. Used in global_contentviews.pt
        """
        context = aq_inner(self.context)
        context_url = context.absolute_url()

        request_url = self.request['ACTUAL_URL']
        request_url_path = request_url[len(context_url):]

        if request_url_path.startswith('/'):
            request_url_path = request_url_path[1:]
```

This is the violating call in CMFPlone RegistrationTool which triggers rendering a full `main_template.pt` even if there is no consumer for it:

```
security.declarePublic('registeredNotify')
def registeredNotify(self, new_member_id):
    """ Wrapper around registeredNotify """
    membership = getToolByName(self, 'portal_membership')
    utils = getToolByName(self, 'plone_utils')
    member = membership.getMemberById(new_member_id)

    ...

    return self.mail_password_response(self, self.REQUEST)
```

Sample traceback:

```
  Error in test test_logout_smartcard (xxxtesting.ui.test_smartcard.TestSmartcard)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 318, in run
        self.setUp()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-packages/xxxtesting/xxxtesting/ui/test_smartcard.py", line 193, in setUp
        self.xxx_helper.create_all()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-packages/xxxtesting/xxxtesting/xxxhelper.py", line 594, in create_all
        self.create_xxx_manager("xxx_manager")
      File "/Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-packages/xxxtesting/xxxtesting/xxxhelper.py", line 412, in create_xxx_manager
        mem.update(**data)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.remember-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/Products/remember/content/member.py", line 653, in update
        triggerAutomaticTransitions(self)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.remember-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/Products/remember/Extensions/workflow.py", line 34, in triggerAutomaticTransitions
        wf_tool.doActionFor(ob, 'trigger')
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.6-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py", line 241, in doActionFor
        wfs, ob, action, wf.doActionFor, (ob, action) + args, kw)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.6-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFCore/WorkflowTool.py", line 552, in _invokeWithNotification
        res = func(*args, **kw)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.DCWorkflow-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/DCWorkflow/DCWorkflow.py", line 282, in doActionFor
        self._changeStateOf(ob, tdef, kw)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.DCWorkflow-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/DCWorkflow/DCWorkflow.py", line 421, in _changeStateOf
        sdef = self._executeTransition(ob, tdef, kwargs)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.DCWorkflow-2.2.4-py2.7.egg/Products/DCWorkflow/DCWorkflow.py", line 474, in _executeTransition
        script(sci)  # May throw an exception.
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ExternalMethod-2.13.0-py2.7.egg/Products/ExternalMethod/ExternalMethod.py", line 241, in __call__
        return f(self.aq_parent.this(), *args, **kw)
       - __traceback_info__: ((<Products.DCWorkflow.Expression.StateChangeInfo instance at 0x107492e18>,), {}, None)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.remember-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/Products/remember/Extensions/workflow.py", line 64, in register
        return obj.register()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-eggs/Products.xxxHospital/Products/xxxHospital/content/xxxUser.py", line 194, in register
        BaseMember.register(self)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.remember-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/Products/remember/content/member.py", line 718, in register
        rtool.registeredNotify(self.getId())
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.1.6-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/RegistrationTool.py", line 345, in registeredNotify
        return self.mail_password_response(self, self.REQUEST)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 322, in __call__
        return self._bindAndExec(args, kw, None)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Shared/DC/Scripts/Bindings.py", line 359, in _bindAndExec
        return self._exec(bound_data, args, kw)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.6-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFCore/FSPageTemplate.py", line 237, in _exec
        result = self.pt_render(extra_context=bound_names)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFCore-2.2.6-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFCore/FSPageTemplate.py", line 177, in pt_render
        self, source, extra_context
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/PageTemplate.py", line 79, in pt_render
        showtal=showtal)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.pagetemplate-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/pagetemplate/pagetemplate.py", line 113, in pt_render
        strictinsert=0, sourceAnnotations=sourceAnnotations)()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 271, in __call__
        self.interpret(self.program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 888, in do_useMacro
        self.interpret(macro)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 533, in do_optTag_tal
        self.do_optTag(stuff)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 518, in do_optTag
        return self.no_tag(start, program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 513, in no_tag
        self.interpret(program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 954, in do_defineSlot
        self.interpret(block)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 533, in do_optTag_tal
        self.do_optTag(stuff)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 518, in do_optTag
        return self.no_tag(start, program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 513, in no_tag
        self.interpret(program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 858, in do_defineMacro
        self.interpret(macro)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 852, in do_condition
        self.interpret(block)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
        structure = self.engine.evaluateStructure(expr)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 218, in evaluateStructure
        text = super(ZopeContext, self).evaluateStructure(expr)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tales-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/tales.py", line 696, in evaluate
        return expression(self)
       - file:/Users/mikko/code/xxx-dev/src/xxx-packages/plonetheme.xxxexternal/plonetheme/xxxexternal/skins/plonetheme_xxxexternal_custom_templates/main_template.pt
       - Line 83, Column 20
       - Expression: <StringExpr u'plone.contentviews'>
       - Names:
          {'container': <PloneSite at /plone>,
           'context': <RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
           'default': <object object at 0x10204e970>,
           'here': <RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
           'loop': {},
           'nothing': None,
           'options': {'args': (<RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
                                <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:55001>)},
           'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x107704c00>,
           'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:55001>,
           'root': <Application at >,
           'template': <FSPageTemplate at /plone/mail_password_response used for /plone/portal_registration>,
           'traverse_subpath': [],
           'user': <PloneUser 'admin'>}
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.contentprovider-3.7.2-py2.7.egg/zope/contentprovider/tales.py", line 80, in __call__
        return provider.render()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.viewletmanager-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/plone/app/viewletmanager/manager.py", line 154, in render
        return BaseOrderedViewletManager.render(self)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.viewletmanager-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/plone/app/viewletmanager/manager.py", line 85, in render
        return u'\n'.join([viewlet.render() for viewlet in self.viewlets])
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.1.13-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py", line 48, in render
        return self.index()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/Five/browser/pagetemplatefile.py", line 125, in __call__
        return self.im_func(im_self, *args, **kw)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/Five/browser/pagetemplatefile.py", line 59, in __call__
        sourceAnnotations=getattr(debug_flags, 'sourceAnnotations', 0),
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.pagetemplate-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/pagetemplate/pagetemplate.py", line 113, in pt_render
        strictinsert=0, sourceAnnotations=sourceAnnotations)()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 271, in __call__
        self.interpret(self.program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 852, in do_condition
        self.interpret(block)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 531, in do_optTag_tal
        self.no_tag(stuff[-2], stuff[-1])
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 513, in no_tag
        self.interpret(program)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
        handlers[opcode](self, args)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 583, in do_setLocal_tal
        self.engine.setLocal(name, self.engine.evaluateValue(expr))
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tales-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/tales.py", line 696, in evaluate
        return expression(self)
       - /Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.1.13-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/contentviews.pt
       - Line 6, Column 4
       - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/prepareObjectTabs'>
       - Names:
          {'args': (),
           'container': <RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
           'context': <RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
           'default': <object object at 0x10204e970>,
           'here': <RegistrationTool at /plone/portal_registration used for /plone/portal_memberdata/xxx_manager>,
           'loop': {},
           'nothing': None,
           'options': {},
           'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x107afe050>,
           'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:55001>,
           'root': <Application at >,
           'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x105dfb810>,
           'traverse_subpath': [],
           'user': <PloneUser 'admin'>,
           'view': <Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.ContentViewsViewlet object at 0x10868c050>,
           'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x107ff1f90>}
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.tales-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/expressions.py", line 217, in __call__
        return self._eval(econtext)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 155, in _eval
        return render(ob, econtext.vars)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 117, in render
        ob = ob()
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.memoize-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/memoize/view.py", line 47, in memogetter
        value = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.1.13-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py", line 258, in prepareObjectTabs
        request_url = self.request['ACTUAL_URL']
      File "/Users/mikko/code/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.15-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/HTTPRequest.py", line 1372, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError, key
    KeyError: 'ACTUAL_URL'
```

Comment: Better to include all detail in your question here and not rely on external websites. If Plone ever decided to switch issue trackers, your link would be broken making your question useless to future visitors.

Comment: Good point! Added inline details in the question.

Comment: I do think your case is a little esoteric and I wonder if you are approaching it from the correct direction. Perhaps not triggering the registration email at all (disabling the feature in your test setup) would be a better approach?